# Is it possible to change type function behavior?

Tags: python, built-in

We can change behavior of `str(object)` function by defining `__str__` in object class. Is it possible to do so with `type` function? I'm just curious, none use case.

Try with `__class__` doesn't work:

```
class A:
    def __class__(self):
        print(1)
        return "x"

obj = A()
print(type(obj))
```

it doesn't print `1` or do anything with `x`. It just prints `<class '__main__.A'>` as usual.

Comment: You can modidy the ```__class__``` attribute. Doing this is probably not recommended

Comment: @Lcj I tried and nothing changed. Have you tried? I think this trick was working some versions ago.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz It worked in my 3.8.2 idle shell. Maybe it works only in specific versions.

Comment: @Lcj check my edited question. In your case `1` is printed?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz I didn't mean to define a ```__class__``` method, but to set the ```__class__``` attribute. Example ```obj.__class__ = B``` then type(obj) will return class B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a metaclass:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return "Fire"

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(type(A()))
# Prints "Fire"
```

Comment: Nice, it works to a point. When I gave `print(1)` to `__repr__` (before return "Fire") it is not printed when `type(A())` called. It prints only with `print(type(A()))` so I guess that only changes representation of `type`, no `type` behavior.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Repr is called on `print`. You can define a `__init__` method on the metaclass which is called when the type is initialized.

Comment: This doesn't change what `type` does, only what you see when the type object is printed. Defining an `__init__` on the metaclass likewise doesn't change what `type` does (at least, in the OP's example; it can change the behaviour when `type` is used to construct the class).

Comment: @kaya3 Completely correct. You can change the behavior of the type of an object, but not the behavior of the built in function `type` itself using this method.

Comment: mousetail example does (I guess) exactly what changing `__str__` method does. It doesn't change `str` behavior, it changes  what `str` means for that one class. That was what I wanted. We can use `forbiddenfruit` package for permanent changes.